# Click Hyperlink on Main Sheet to filter Data on Second Sheet- Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have a main worksheet with names in column 2 that contain some hyperlinks. I would like to click these certain links to filter data in a second sheet called "Reference". I keep getting a  Runtime 424 error "Object Required". Appreciate any assistance.

Heres what i have so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

If ActiveCell.Column = 2 Then

    OB.ListObjects("Reference").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=ActiveCell.Value
    Reference.Activate
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are `OB` and `Reference` the codenames of your sheets?

Comment: Yes, these sheets were renamed to OB and Reference. OB being the main sheet with the hyperlinks